# How to have a line beside a bulleted list

Tags: lists

[image]Normally a list looks just like this:

- text here

  - some sub text
  - some sub text 2
- text again

But I would like a line through the text

```
- some text
| - hello
| - hi
- another text
- another part of the list, which has no line.
```

How do I have these "toggable" connected items? Some times those are not connected.

Comment: Sorry, what? I have no idea what you're actually asking for. Can you give an example? Perhaps an image?

Comment: I've added an image, specifically i'm trying to make bullets on my CV and want to show to things are together or in a series.

Comment: Looks like [How do you put a vertical line through the bullets in a list? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239978/how-do-you-put-a-vertical-line-through-the-bullets-in-a-list) / [tikz pgf - Bulleted list with vertical lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454744/bulleted-list-with-vertical-lines) / [List environment with vertical lines along nested lists - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270939/list-environment-with-vertical-lines-along-nested-lists)

Comment: Thank you. That helped.