# Vertical lines in nested itemize environment

Tags: itemize, line, nesting

Looking to add vertical lines that separates the head levels in nested itemize environment as shown in the image.

There is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270939/list-environment-with-vertical-lines-along-nested-lists). But I want to keep the bullets as shown in the image.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item Head Level 1: some text some text some text some text some text some text some 
 text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

   \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-level 1: some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

    \begin{itemize}
        \item subsub-level 1: some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\item Head Level 2: some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-level 2: some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

    \begin{itemize}
        \item subsub-level 2: some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]